# how to create a column in a dataframe based on the order of another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data.frame

```
casenum<-c('510-1','510-2','510-2','510-3','510-3','510-3','510-4')
chargecode<-c('AA','BB','DD','FF','GG','DD','ZZ')

df<-data.frame(casenum,chargecode)

  casenum chargecode
1   510-1         AA
2   510-2         BB
3   510-2         DD
4   510-3         FF
5   510-3         GG
6   510-3         DD
7   510-4         ZZ
```

Basically I want to create a third column called `count` that indicates if the charge code associated with a case is the first count, the second count or the third count. so that it looks like the following

```
  casenum chargecode count
1   510-1         AA   1
2   510-2         BB   1
3   510-2         DD   2
4   510-3         FF   1
5   510-3         GG   2
6   510-3         DD   3
7   510-4         ZZ   1
```

I used the following code

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(casenum,chargecode)%>%
mutate(count = as.integer(factor(chargecode, levels = unique(chargecode))))
```

how ever it doesn't provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this using `dplyr`:

```
library("dplyr")
df %>% 
  group_by(casenum) %>% 
  # Add row number within a group, i.e., the order of occurrence
  mutate(count = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```